# Extracting JSON data from node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

With a request to Twitter for example:
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=stephenfry&include_entities=true

I can extract an element like followers_count using `result["followers_count"]`

I've tried a similar request to LastFM but their JSON is structured differently as it's a translation of their default XML.

With their demo request:
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json

How would I get the listeners value?

I've tried

`result["listeners"]`

`result["artist.listeners"]`

`result["artist.stats.listeners"]`

I understand I need to access a node, but have no idea how to go about it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nested hash, so you can reach it with:

```
result["artist"]["stats"]["listeners"]
```

Example:

```
require('open-uri')
require('json')

result = JSON.parse(open('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json').read)
result["artist"]["stats"]["listeners"].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

The Last.fm data is a series of nested hashes, so you need to access them as such. Give the following  a try, it should do the trick:

```
result["artist"]["listeners"]
```